# Trying to update column on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update my table from another tmp table called fake_email but when I ran the following:

```
update users
SET email = fake_email2.email
FROM fake_email2
where users.id = fake_email2.id
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
```

Is there a way to update it?

Comment: There is email exist constraint on email column. You cannot do that.

Comment: Likely there are duplicates in your `fake_email2` table. Check if you get any results for `SELECT email FROM fake_email2 GROUP BY email HAVING count(*) > 1;`. The e-mail addresses appearing have duplicates.

Comment: First you need to resolve e-mail contention. There must be no doubles in the set of fake_email2  table rows + existing users not present in fake_email2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `users` table has a *Constraint* on it that requires the email fields to be unique for all rows in the `users` table.

Run the following query to locate the current rows that match your incoming data set:

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, fake_email2.email, *
FROM users
INNER JOIN fake_email2 ON users.id = fake_email2.id
```

In fact, you can find the duplicates with this query:

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, fake_email2.email
FROM users
INNER JOIN fake_email2 ON users.id = fake_email2.id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT u2.email FROM users as u2 where u2.Id <> users.Id AND u2.email = fake_email2.email )
```

So you have two options:

1. Remove the unique constraint
2. Remove the Row that has a duplicate email address

> Publishing a list of the data, structures and the *create* script for the constraint might help with specifics, but at the end of the day, your **DBA** has specified that the email address is unique for each row, you should not try to circumvent that.